# BackgroundWorker only reporting progress in debug mode

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

I have a program that reads some data, then creates a big datatable based on this and finally exports this datatable to a .csv file. As the generation of the table takes quite long I have created a backgroundworker that should show in a listbox on my mainform where the program is in the process.

Below a summary of my code:

```
    private readonly BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

    public void get_data()
    {
        worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();

    }

    private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        worker.ReportProgress(1, "Starting");

        mydata = read_file();

        worker.ReportProgress(1, "Step 1 done!");

        fullmodel = combine_data(mydata);

        worker.ReportProgress(1, "Step 2 done!");

        DataTableToCSV(fullmodel, ';');

    }

    private void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        MainWindow.listBox.Items.Add(e.UserState);      

    }

    private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    { 

    }
```

This works fine when I run my program in debugging mode of VS2015, "Starting", "Step 1 done!" and "Step 2 done!" appear in the listbox when they should. However when I run the application outside of Visual Studio the ProgressChanged event does only seem to be triggered once - "Starting" is shown in the listbox as expected but only when the backgroundworker is done, the other two entries that should be reported while it is running are shown in the listbox at once and the UI freezes while the program is running.

Comment: I can't reproduce your scenario with empty `read_file`, `combine_data` and `DataTableToCSV` methods so I think that it can be a problem with this methods. For example, read_file can thrown an exception because can't find file on disk or something similar.

Comment: @bommelding: no it's a simple single-threaded program, so there shouldn't be anything else running and the messages appear in the order that they should appear - I also have some more worker.ReportProgress(....) in the three methods that are being called and they also appear as they should as long as I am in debugging mode

Comment: When release mode and debug mode runs differently always go back the bin folder of you project and compare the timestamp of the two executables.  Usually you will find the one that doesn't work is older than the one that works so simply recompile the one that doesn't work.  I usually just delete the entire bin folder to force the code to recompile.

Comment: You left the code that caused this problem out of the snippet.  What you are *actually* doing is calling ReportProgress() far too often.  Like doing so for every line in the CSV file.  This causes a firehose bug, the UI thread gets poked far too frequently and starts burning 100% core trying to keep up.  And doesn't get around to the low priority jobs anymore, like painting.  Worse in the Release build since it runs faster.  Only produce output at a rate that a human eye can reasonably keep up with and you'll never have this problem.

Comment: Thx Hans! - seems I was simply calling .ReportProgress way too often and the UI thread just couldn't keep up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hans Passant's comment above was the right hint. In the methods I was calling there were quite a few `.ReportProgress` implemented in some loops and it seems the UI thread could not keep up with this (while there was no exception triggered). When running the program in debugging mode the program is running a lot slower for some reason and then the UI thread doesn't seem to have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your scenario with empty `read_file()`, `combine_data()` and `DataTableToCSV()` methods so I think that it can be a problem with this methods. For example, `read_file()` can thrown an exception because can't find file on disk or something similar.

The feature of background exception thrown is that it does not stop the main application.

via [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork.aspx):

> If the operation raises an exception that your code does not handle, the BackgroundWorker catches the exception and passes it into the RunWorkerCompleted event handler, where it is exposed as the Error property of System.ComponentModel..::.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs. If you are running under the Visual Studio debugger, the debugger will break at the point in the DoWork event handler where the unhandled exception was raised.

So, yo can add code to the `worker_RunWorkerCompleted()` method and check `Exception` was thrown.